# tips for speeding up outlook 2007

Tags: performance, microsoft-outlook-2007

Does anyone have any tips for speeding up outlook 2007?

Answer (score 4):

Out of all the tips these are the top 5 -

1. Delete attachments
2. Split emails into Archives
3. Compact your PST data files often
4. Download the latest patches from Microsoft
5. Speed up Windows in general by disabling some visual effects

Answer (score 3):

@systech...

Dead right - it is the size of the PST that slows things down.

You don't have to lose the attachments by deleting them. I use "attachment remover" that strips the attachments out to a windows folder and replaces them in the email with a shortcut. So you reduce the size of the PST, but don't lose access to the attachments. I have been very happy with it.

You can find it here http://www.kopf.com.br/outlook/

Be sure that you find a stable home for the attachments - once you strip them off I do not think you can move them without breaking the shortcut.

Do also split the PST into Current email and an archive

Once I had done that, and compacted the PST I saw a dramatic increase Outlook's speed

@Niffle - That was unkind. The questioner wanted to draw on this group's experience and integrity for good and safe answers without having to wade through the 195,000 pages that Google dumps on you. digiguru asked a reasonable question. Having said that, I love "let me google that for you" for endless requests for trivial help for folks who can't try help themselves before bugging me.